# Tradingview alertcondition(condition, title, message)

Tags: alert, pine-script, trading

I want to create an alert condition whenever `ema(close,20) > ema(close,50) > ema(close,100)` is `true` along with other conditions from the original script. This for Buy alert. Reverse is for sell.

I am a noob and I am trying to add alert to the original script.
How can I add the above condition to alert condition?

I tried simply putting `and ema(close,20) > ema(close,50) > ema(close,100)`
But it gives me error:

> Cannot call 'operator >' with arguments (series[bool], series[float]);
> available overloads: >(float, float) => bool; >(input float, input
> float) => input bool; >(const float, const float) => const bool;
> (float, series[float]) => series[bool]; >(series[float], float) => series[bool]; >(series[float], series[float]) => series[bool]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each comparison operator, two arguments are required, just as for logical operators.

```
ema(close,20) > ema(close,50) and ema(close,50) > ema(close,100)
```